# App icon missing when installed via HockeyApp

Tags: hockeyapp

I'm wondering, why Hockeyapp is not showing IOS app icon (splash screen works well) when installed via this platform ? Any ideas ?
App installed via Xcode on real device, or any of emulators works as expected, but not when installed via hockeyapp.
Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Are you using any kind of beta icon?

Comment: Well, on real device i will see proper icon, but on hockyapp i see generic nativescript icon.